# Function Call for Referenced Array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, reference

Trying to do a function call for an array, but the error: cannot refer to template array without an argument list keeps coming up. What is the best way to pass this array by reference to the main function?

```
using namespace std;

//function prototype
int readInput(vector<int> &vect);
void sort(vector<int> &vect, int &array, int &size);

int main()
{
vector<int> values;
int sum, avg;

sum = readInput(values);

sort(&array, &size); //cannot refer to template array without an argument list 

return 0;
}

int readInput(vector<int> &vect) 
{

int count;
int total = 0;

 ifstream inputFile("TopicFin.txt"); //open file

 if(!inputFile)
{
    return 0; // if file is not found, return 0
}

 while(inputFile >> count) //read file
 vect.push_back(count); //add to file

 for (int count = 0; count < vect.size(); count++)
 total+=vect[count]; //sum data in vector

return total;

}

void sort(vector<int> &vect, int array[], int &size)
{

for (int count = 0; count < vect.size(); count++)
   array[count] = vect[count];


int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

for(startScan = 0; startScan < (size-1); startScan++)
{
    minIndex = startScan;
    minValue = array[startScan];
    for(int index = startScan + 1; index < size; index++)
    {
        if (array[index] < minValue)
        {
            minValue = array[index];
            minIndex = index;
        }
    }

    array[minIndex] = array[startScan];
    array[startScan] = minValue;
}

for(int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    cout << array[count] << " " << endl;
}
```

Comment: `sort()` requires 3 parameters while you only provide it 2.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're calling `sort(&array...`, while not having `array` declared in your main, so compiler assumes you refer to `std::array` template and chokes. You need to declare both `array` and `size` in your code, and pass the third parameter to `sort`.

Comment: Hmm, I try to so, but errors keep popping up. Here's what I try:   const int SIZE = values.size(); int arr[SIZE];

Comment: Did you fix your `sort` call? `sort(values, arr, SIZE);`. Also, to pass an array by reference, you're supposed to pass it as `int*`, I believe. So your function header would be `void sort(vector<int> &vect, int* array, int size);`.

Comment: @John That’s illegal C++. Array sizes need to be *compile time constants*. Your value is `const` but not known at compile time since it’s the result of a function call.

Comment: Technically, yes. I think that compilers allow variable-sized arrays, though (however they're not resizable).

Comment: I fixed the sort, but once I change it to sort(values, arr, SIZE) the error: no matching function to call sort appears.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski: That's C99. C++ never allows VLAs.